# How to stop/detect page refresh in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I am learning PHP websocket. I am doing text message exchange text between two users as chat.

When I refresh the last message is sent repeatedly. I use

JQuery

```
 $("#messageform").submit( function(ev) {

       ev.preventDefault();
       //message sent here
 }
```

Please help me either to detect or find if the user have refresh page with F5 or Ctr+R. In nutshell, I want to stop repetition of last message when refresh. Any solutions out-of-the-box will do.

Comment: Do you want to detect if it _was_ reloaded or _before_ it gets reloaded?

Comment: I want to detect if it was reloaded.

Comment: Ok. Then, set a cookie on `unload`. If that cookie exists when the page gets loaded, then it was refreshed/reloaded.

Comment: Why do you get repetition of last message on refresh/reload?  It seems you could just fix that and let the end user refresh whenever they want to.

Comment: few frameworks use Ajax to monitor page lifecycle, and sends requests to server, on each action like domready, page reload, etc. so it could be helpful to monitor this data on server side.

Comment: I think I have to try with cookie. Appreciate for your idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use beforeunload which detects all your script being unloaded. ie Refresh, Tab close or Window Close

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function ()
{
   // conditions here
    return true/false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unload` event for this

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  return "Bye now!";
});
```